# Drawing an imperfect circle

Tags: graphics, random, language-agnostic, geometry

Programatically drawing a perfect circle is not all that difficult.  It's based on some very simple math, afterall.  You input two parameters (a center and a radius) and output the circle.

But if you don't have tools to help you, drawing a circle freeform (as in holding a pen in your hand) is very difficult!  If I wanted to simulate a person trying to draw a circle, is there any algorithm I could use that takes three parameters (a center, a radius, and a "wrongness factor") and uses the magnitude of the third value to create random imperfections in the circle, while still producing something that looks recognizably like a person trying to draw a circle?

Comment: Here's one approach -- http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs -- which you may be able to adapt or adopt for your purposes.  If you google hard enough I think you'll find implementations in other languages too.

Comment: http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/upjDy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot the circle as a series of arcs, both "inwards" and "outwards", recalculating the correct center for each segment needed to keep the endpoint of the arc within a certain distance of the actual circumference.

Answer (score 1):

A circle drawn by free hand is *random* but still looks *continuous*. Adding noise to the radius might result in jumps which look unrealistic.

A slight modification can somewhat resolve this issue. Using a Markov matrix, divide the noise into `N` levels and have only tri-diagonal entries. This will result in randomness but yet it can only transit to prev/next levels only. Making it look continuous.